# Caratheodory and Riesz

Tags: measure-theory

This is related to a previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95814/conditions-for-non-triviality-of-caratheodory-measureBlockquote).

**Carathéodory's construction** assigns to each outer measure $$\phi^+:\mathcal{P}(S)\to[0,\infty]$$ a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ where the restriction $\phi$ of $\phi^+$ is a measure. $\Sigma$ is easy to define: It is the collection of all those $X\subseteq S$ such that for any $A\subseteq S$, we have $$\phi^+(A)=\phi^+(A\cap X)+\phi^+(A\setminus X).$$

**Riesz representation theorem** also considers an outer measure and extracts from it a $\sigma$-algebra where the outer measure is a (nice, essentially regular) measure. In this case, $S$ is assumed to be Hausdorff and locally compact. We are given a positive linear functional $\Lambda\in C_c(S)$ (the collection of continuous complex-valued functions on $S$ with compact support). We start by defining $$\phi^+(V)=\sup\{\Lambda f\mid {\rm supp}(f)\subset V\}$$ for $V$ open, and then extend $\phi^+$ to all ${\mathcal P}(S)$ by $$\phi^+(E)=\inf\{\phi^+(V)\mid V\text{ is open, and }E\subseteq V\}.$$ This is an outer measure. The $\sigma$-algebra one associates to $\phi^+$ is $\mathcal{M}$, the collection of all $X\subseteq S$ such that for any compact $K\subseteq S$ we have that $\phi^+(X\cap K)<\infty$ and $$\phi^+(X\cap K)=\sup\{\phi^+(C)\mid C\text{ is compact, and }C\subseteq X\cap K\}.$$ Again, the restriction $\phi$ of $\phi^+$ to $\mathcal{M}$ is a measure.

> Are there any reasonable circumstances under which we should expect that $\Sigma=\mathcal{M}$, or at least that one of the two containments holds?

Comment: The answer is yes. The inclusion is easy in one direction and, in the other direction you can reduce to the case where $A$ is open and, then, to the case where $A$ is compact, so that the two definitions reduce to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might misunderstand your question, but it seems that you are asking about the distinction
between the measure and "essential measure" in Bourbaki measure theory ("presque partut"
vs. "localment presque partut"). In locally compact paracompact spaces there is not such a 
"byzantine" distinction (where the term "byzantine" is used by A.Weil is the comments in
his collected papers). However, the collections of measurable sets is the same for the
two measures; essentially, the "local" version is a "smaller" measure with some sets
with infinite (total variation) measure for the initial measure which became of 
(total variation) measure zero for the local version.

Comment: I should have checked Bourbaki's book. Many thanks.